# First login not work, but second login is work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, authentication, login-control

I'm trying to learn MVC coding, but I have a last small problem. First login not work, but second login is work. It everytime works like that.

My controller codes:

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
        }
        return View();
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string txtUsername, string txtPassword)
    {            
        Customer loggedInUser = db.Customers.Where(x=> x.Username == txtUsername && x.Password == txtPassword).FirstOrDefault();
        if (loggedInUser == null)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please check your username and password.')</script>");
            return View();
        }
        else
        {                
            Session["UserID"] = loggedInUser.ID;
            Response.Redirect("/Home/Index");
            return View();
        }                      
    }
```

I using this Session["UserID"] on Index page for to understand that I'm logged in.

My Index View codes:

```
@section Login{

    @if (Session["UserID"] == null)
    {
        <li><a href="/Home/Login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"> </span> &nbsp Log In</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Register"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> </span> Create an Account</a></li>
    }
    else
    {    
        int userID = (int)Session["UserID"];
        <li><a href="/Home/UserDetail/@userID"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"> </span> User Detail</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/Orders"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift"> </span> &nbsp Orders</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Home/LogOut"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"> </span> &nbsp Log Out</a></li>
    }
}
```

I investigate this with breakpoint on VS. In the first login attempt Session["UserID"] is fill on controller, but Session["UserID"] is look like null on Index View page in first login attempt. I give second try and this time Session["UserID"] comes not null on Index View page.

Thanks for anyone help and so sorry my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have solved the problem this way

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(string txtUsername, string txtPassword)
    {            
        Customer loggedInUser = db.Customers.Where(x=> x.Username == txtUsername && x.Password == txtPassword).FirstOrDefault();
        if (loggedInUser == null)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Please check your username and password.')</script>");
            return View();
        }
        else
        {                
            Session["UserID"] = loggedInUser.ID;
            //Response.Redirect("/Home/Index"); that's not good way
            return Redirect("/Home/Index"); //this is the good way
        }                      
    }
```